# Crawling redirected url in scrapy

Tags: python, url, redirect, scrapy

I am working in scrapy.

I am fetching a site which consists of a list of urls.

So I requested the main url in `start_url` and I got all the href tags(links to fetch data) in  a list, I again requested each and every url in the list further for fetching data, but some of the urls are redirecting like below:

```
Redirecting (301) to <GET example.com/sch/mobile-68745.php> from Redirecting (301) to <GET example.com/sch/mobile-8974.php>
```

I came to know that scrapy ignores the redirected links, but I want to catch the redirected url and want to scrape the same like the url with 200 status

Is there anyway to catch that redirect url and scrape the data from them, I mean do we need disable redirect middleware? Or do we need to use any meta tag in Request command, can youu provide me an example of that?

Comment: >i came to know that scrapy ignores the redirected links, but i want to catch the redirected url and want to scrape the same like the url with 200 status< it's not true - scrapy does not ignore redirected links. When a page has 301 status or a `meta refresh` instruction is met in the content, the response is not passed to the callback, a message about redirection is shown, a new request is issued with the same callback but with new url. So the redirected url is not ignored, unless it's from another domain or an already visited url *(filtered by dupe middleware)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got no experience with Scrapy, but apparently, you can define *middlewares* that change they way Scrapy works when resolving content.

There is the [RedirectMiddleware](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect) that supports and handles redirects out of the box, so all you’d need to do is to enable that.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'apy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 123,
}
```

Comment: I think by default it is enabled